# How to end conversation grafecully?

Tags: java, grpc, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I'm using Google Assistant Service via GRPC generated with the latest embedded_assistant.proto

I'm getting 100% Errors on Google Assistant API - even though my app works properly, I believe I am getting the errors due to improper handling the end of the conversation.

Could someone advice how to properly end the conversation ?

Google Assistant API reports an error caused by following method:

[image]

```
public io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<com.google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.AssistRequest> assist(
    io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<com.google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.AssistResponse> responseObserver) {
  return asyncUnimplementedStreamingCall(METHOD_ASSIST, responseObserver);
}
```

Here is how I start and end the conversation(based on samples):

```
public void startConversation() {
    mConversationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    mRequestHandler.post(() -> mRequestCallback.onRequestStart());
    mAssistantHandler.post(() -> {

        DialogStateIn.Builder dialogStateInBuilder = DialogStateIn.newBuilder();
        getLocation();
        if (mDeviceLocation != null) {
            dialogStateInBuilder.setDeviceLocation(mDeviceLocation);
        }
        dialogStateInBuilder.setLanguageCode(mLanguageCode);

        AssistConfig.Builder assistConfigBuilder = AssistConfig.newBuilder()
                .setAudioInConfig(mAudioInConfig)
                .setAudioOutConfig(mAudioOutConfig)
                .setDeviceConfig(mDeviceConfig);
        if (mScreenOutConfig != null) {
            assistConfigBuilder.setScreenOutConfig(mScreenOutConfig);
        }
        assistConfigBuilder.setDialogStateIn(dialogStateInBuilder.build());

        mAssistantRequestObserver = mAssistantService.assist(mAssistantResponseObserver);

        mAssistantRequestObserver.onNext(
                AssistRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setConfig(assistConfigBuilder.build())
                        .build());
    });
}


public void stopConversation() {
    mAssistantRequestObserver = null;
    mConversationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    mConversationHandler.post(() -> mConversationCallback.onConversationFinished());
}
```

Also, is there any way to get this error details from the Google Console ?

Comment: Have you tried `mAssistantRequestObserver.onCompleted()`? Calling it ends the request stream.

Comment: If you go to Stackdriver logging in the console, it may provide more details on why the error is happening.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung unfortunately that's not the case but good try anyway, I added the following to my stopConversation() method:         `if (mAssistantRequestObserver != null) {
            mAssistantRequestObserver.onCompleted();
            mAssistantRequestObserver = null;
        }` @NickFelker I can't see any logs in StackDriver regarding the errors mentioned. My assumption that it's due to not closing the conversation gracefully is because the mentioned errors come with Response Code = 499.